# Do I re-train the model on whole training data

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I have an image dataset for multi-class image classification- training & testing images. I trained and saved my model (as .h5 file) on training data, using 80-20% as train-validation split.

Now, I want to predict the classes for test images.

Which option is better and is it always the case?

1. Use the trained model as it is for "test images" prediction.
2. Train the saved model on whole training data (i.e, including 20% of the validation images) and then do predictions on test images. But in case, there will be no validation data, and hence, how does the model ensure that it keeps the loss to be minimum during training.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already properly trained the model, you do not need to retrain again. (Unless you are doing something specific with transfer learning). The whole purpose of having test data is to use as a test case to see how well you model did on unseen data.

Comment: So, it's better to let the model be trained on only 80% of training data (since, 20% of training data was used as validation). But isn't it better that i use 100% of training data, since more data means it will be able to predict better? I am a beginner in modelling and thought more data the better.

Comment: Yes, that is Machine learning 101. The 80/20 rule will help with training. If using something like keras, it is preferred. If you don't have this split, your model will not know if it is doing well on brand new data. Also if you have no test data your model will simply overfit and do worse on new data. I understand your logic but  if you want to use more data, keep the 80/20 rule and get more data.